# IntelliJ plugin creates files in wrong folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I've recently started work on someone else's codebase developing an IntelliJ plugin. It uses the Apache Commons FileUtils class to create files retrieved from an external service. This service provides a relative path to the file (e.g. `src/stuff/file.txt`) and its contents as strings, which are then used to create the file.

When I debug the plugin, the files are created using `FileUtils.writeStringToFile`, but instead of in the current project, they end up in the IntelliJ IDE install directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.2\bin`)

Is there a setting I've missed or do I have to look for the current project's source directory in code somehow?

UPDATE
What is happening exactly is that the plugin lets me create a new module type. To do this, some extra steps are added to the modulewizard. One of these steps involves selecting, downloading and creating files to be used in the project. When the wizard has run through the custom steps, it ends by asking for a project name and directory (this seems to be a default module step provided by IntelliJ?). This means that at the time my project files were downloaded, the project root did not exist so the files are located in a default folder somewhere. Documentation on this seems to be scarce, is there a way to add a step *after* the project name/directory one?

Comment: Try ./src/stuff/file.txt as your relative path.  Should start at the project root.  Where do you set the project root when you create the project?

Comment: @duffymo I found out that the actual project directory is not set up until after the files are created. One of the steps of the new module wizard is getting all the files, but at this point it hasn't asked for a project name/location yet. Can I change the order or is there some event I can use that indicates the wizard has finished?

Comment: I usually tell IntelliJ where I want the project root to be when I create the project.  Are you doing that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There is no setting; if you need to store files in the user's project directory, you need to do that explicitly. Note that an IntelliJ project can have multiple content roots in different directories, so there may not be a single "project directory" as such.